# Colocar efeito de rolagem no meu código

Tags: android, flutter, text

Sou novo no flutter e gostaria de saber como faço para ter aquele efeito de rolagem acho que se chama scrollView, para o usuário ler o restante do texto

O resultado está ficando assim;
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lojavirtual-41732.appspot.com/o/1.PNG?alt=media&token=be2208d7-6631-4d95-b655-7e3bad85e192

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual/screens/login_screen.dart';

class OrdersTabVarejo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[

            Text("Leia com atenção\n\n"
                "Estamos sempre desenvolvendo novos recursos e tecnologias para melhorar nossos serviços. "
                "Por exemplo, investimos em inteligência artificial que usa aprendizado de máquina para detectar e "
                "bloquear spam e malware, além de oferecer recursos inovadores, como tradução simultânea. Como "
                "parte dessa melhoria contínua, às vezes adicionamos ou removemos recursos e funcionalidades, "
                "aumentamos ou diminuímos limites para nossos serviços e começamos a oferecer novos serviços ou "
                "deixamos de oferecer os antigos. Estamos sempre desenvolvendo novos recursos e tecnologias para "
                "melhorar nossos serviços. Por exemplo, investimos em inteligência artificial que usa aprendizado de "
                "melhorar nossos serviços. Por exemplo, investimos em inteligência artificial que usa aprendizado de",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,),
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Continuar", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>LoginScreen())
                );
                CustomScrollView(

                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apenas crie um widget com funcionalidade de [rolagem](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/scrolling).

Você pode ter mais de um widget rolável na sua tela, se você quer que a tela inteira seja rolável, você pode adicionar esse widget logo na raiz da sua arvore de widgets:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[

        Text("Leia com atenção\n\n"
            "Estamos sempre desenvolvendo novos recursos e tecnologias para melhorar nossos serviços. "
            "Por exemplo, investimos em inteligência artificial que usa aprendizado de máquina para detectar e "
            "bloquear spam e malware, além de oferecer recursos inovadores, como tradução simultânea. Como "
            "parte dessa melhoria contínua, às vezes adicionamos ou removemos recursos e funcionalidades, "
            "aumentamos ou diminuímos limites para nossos serviços e começamos a oferecer novos serviços ou "
            "deixamos de oferecer os antigos. Estamos sempre desenvolvendo novos recursos e tecnologias para "
            "melhorar nossos serviços. Por exemplo, investimos em inteligência artificial que usa aprendizado de "
            "melhorar nossos serviços. Por exemplo, investimos em inteligência artificial que usa aprendizado de",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,),
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Continuar", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>LoginScreen())
            );
            CustomScrollView(

            );
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```